# Crash reporting- cannot find log files from my app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I recently "installed" my app on my iPhone for testing.  Everything was running fine but then on occasion, the app would just stop running, and send me back to the home page.

I checked for a crash log but there is none to be found.  The directory is there, but no log.  I then noticed then when I ran a few other apps, on occasion they would also crash.

Does this mean it is not my app that is crashing if their is no log?  If not, any pointers on where to look or possibly how to create a log?

On other thing:  I was able to recreate this once in the simulator but when it quit and took me to the home screen, it did not show any error in the debug window.

Ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to check out this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845630/iphone-crash-catching-options-on-published-apps

Comment: I would wager that what you saw in the simulator is different than on the device.  Shingoo's answer below is, if not correct, should be considered before proceeding.  More likely than not, you are exhausting memory on the device and the iPhone OS is killing your app.

Comment: If it is a memeory issue, could this be the cause:

On start up, I check for a plist file and if found load an array from file, if not create array.  Then after each "level", I take that array and reinitalize it and then randomize it.

Would I need to dealloc the old array first?  Could that be the memory problem?

Comment: That could certainly be a memory issue and, no, you never `dealloc` anything directly.  You `release` it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Crash Catching Options on Published Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845630/iphone-crash-catching-options-on-published-apps)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put some NSLog into the didReceiveMemoryWarning methods of your classes. Maybe you allocated to much memory and the iPhone OS is killing your app because you do not free any memory after the call of that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the crash reports from an app in `window -> Organiser` then click on the device in the left then `Crash Logs` this will show all the crash logs for all the apps on your device